# How to set div height to td height?

Tags: html, css

I have a

```css
.divHeight {
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#deal/{{id}}">
        <div class="text-ellipsis divHeight" style="width:10em">
          <span class="text-cap">{{name}}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In CSS:

```
.divHeight{
    height:40px;
}
```

I want to set div height as td height and my td has padding:10px,so if I am clicking on that padding area my right click functionality is not working.
So, now I want to implement right click on `<tr>` so if I click on anywhere on the tr, td it has to give right-click and it has prompt me to "open in new tab" option. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS:

```
#tdcontent {
    height: 100%;
}

#text-ellipsis divHeight {
    overflow: auto; /* or overflow: hidden; */
}
```

Comment: Hi,As per your suggestion I have applied the same thing for the <div> but it not working.I want to right click anywhere in the <td>.